# When using touchListener in activity how can we get information back to the activity from the listener?

Tags: android, android-activity, listener, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I have an activity in which I have an ImageView and a SeekBar. I registered a listener with imageview1.setOnTouchListener(mylistener) for the ImageView(mylistner is a class). I get the motion events in onTouch method in my listener. I want the program to hide the SeekBar when I touch the Image View. All the Tutorials I watched show how the listener gets the event from the source. But what I am looking for is sending the data back to the source, so that it can hide the SeekBar.

The main question is in touch event handling of an activity how we can get results back from the listener class to the calling class(source)? Is there a better way to do what I want?

should I make another event which will call for the SeekBar? if yes How?

```
public class A extends Activity {
//.....
final SeekBar sb=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
Mylistener mylistener;
mylisetner=new MyListener(getApplicationContext());

ImageView.setOnTouchListener(mylistener);
//.....

}

public class MyListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
//.....

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
final int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK; 
switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:          
       // here how can you get access to the seek bar? or how you inform it to hide?
}
//....

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understood from your question, you want to hide the seekbar when imageview is touched.. right?

try following code in your ontouchlistener....

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {  
 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
     seekbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
     seekbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
}
```

where seekbar is your SEEKBAR :), hold its reference in oncreate.....

Comment: This code will work if the onTouch is handled in the same activity class, but if you make a new class which implements View.OnTouchListener and then you add the onTouch you will have this problem: the seekbar was defined in the activity class which differs from the listener class and can not be defined as public so you wont have access to them.

Comment: MyListener  is in an inner class right ?? if you define seekbar as class variable to activity it will be available in MyListener ...

Comment: MyLIstener is not an inner class.

Comment: hmm  any special requirement for not making it one ?

Comment: I have a custom view which extends view and it needs 5 classes to handle the zoom functionality. If I define all of those classes inside, I will lose code readability. Don't you think?

Comment: when I touch the custom view the seekbar should hide!

Comment: Define a custom event listener as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292712/android-custom-event-listener

Comment: Thank you it worked. I made an event which calls the listener in activity where seekbar can become invisible/visible.