# Creating custom listeners

Tags: android

How to create a custom listener for things like

1.Relavent listener's method should be called if `int` field of the activity reaches a particular value

2.Another method of the listener should be called when Light sensor reads a particular value

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own `Interface` for that. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8293106/1376688) you can find an example.

Hope this helps.