# Android custom listener for an event

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, listener, observer-pattern

I'm trying to fire an event when an integer value is updated, but it's failing. Here's the code I'm using:

**Declaring The Custom Listener**

```
public class fieldactivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    OnModeUpdate modeupdate; //Create custom listener for mode update

    int mode = 1;
```

**Mode Update Code**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fieldsignals);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mode_rotate_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case(R.id.rotate_button):
                mode += 1;
                modeupdate.onEvent(); //Fire Custom Lisentener - Fails On This Line
        }

    }
```

**Interface Code**

```
public interface OnModeUpdate {
//BreakPoint here, but is never reached
        void onEvent();
    }

    public void setModeupdate(OnModeUpdate eventListener) {
        modeupdate = eventListener;
    }
```

The error I am getting is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   alveare.com.plcsignalconverter.fieldactivity$OnModeUpdate.onEvent()'
>   on a null object reference

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You never initialized `modeupdate`. You might look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710809/is-that-a-right-way-of-using-interface-callback/34711257#34711257) to get some insight on how the pattern works.

Comment: u should implement OnModeUpdate in some activity and define what to do in onEvent() method

Comment: You never called `setModeupdate` and you  never implemented the interface

Answer (score 1):

The `NullPointerException` is caused by calling methods on a null referenced object, which means that it has not been initialized.

In your case, the null object is `modeUpdate`. Try to initialize it in the `onCreate()` of your activity.

```
modeupdate = new OnModeUpdate() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent() {
      /**
      * Write the code to handle the case
      */
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

More general name for *listener* is *observer* * design pattern. Speaking the pattern terminology what you're trying to achieve is to make an observer, i.e `modeupdate`, get notified when an event (integer value change) occurrs within an observable object, i.e.`fieldactivity` interacting with a user.

The observer, `modeupdate`, may be of any type and must implement the `OnModeUpdate` interface in order to receive notifications from the observable object. E.g.**

```
public class CustomListener implements OnModeUpdate {
    @Override
    public void onEvent() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can assign the observer (`modeupdate`) within the observable object (`fieldactivity`) by one of the following options (according to your business logic):

- initialize `modeupdate` with an "external" class instance

  ```
  OnModeUpdate modeupdate = new CustomListener();
  ```
- initialize `modeupdate` with an anonymous inner class instance within `fieldactivity` class

  ```
  modeupdate = new OnModeUpdate() {
      @Override
      public void onEvent() {
          // Do stuff regarding the mode change
      }
  };
  ```
- assign `modeupdate` from outside of the `fieldactivity` class by calling `setModeupdate(...)` on the reference to `fieldactivity` instance ***.

Above said explains the cause of `NullPointerException`. You never initialized `modeupdate`. After the initialization of `modeupdate` the `onEvent()` method will be triggered on a button click.

**Note:** you wrote in the comment to your code: *"... BreakPoint here, but is never reached."* It cannot be reached within the interface declaration, only on an instance of the object that implements the interface.

---

<sup>* Another name of the pattern is Subscriber-Publisher pattern.</sup>  
 <sup>** If *OnModeUpdate* interface is declared within *fieldactivity* use *public class CustomListener implements fieldactivity.OnModeUpdate*</sup>  
 <sup>*** Same as you did with the *button* variable by calling *setOnClickListener()* outside of the *Button* class and assigning a listener, i.e. an object (*fieldactivity*) that implements *View.OnClickListener* interface</sup>