# Android : Notified when all Async calls are completed

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, observer-pattern, greenrobot-eventbus

I am stuck in one implementation. I am developing an Android application, into which I integrated 3rd party SDK (library) and calling its APIs. Function calling of SDK is actually Async calls (WebAPI calls called by the library) which gives a response (success or failure).

Now, I am trying to explain the situation by code.

```
for (................) {
    AsyncAPICall (SuccessListener { 
        onSuccess() {
            for (................) {
                AsyncAPICall (SuccessListener { 
                    onSuccess() {
                        for (................) {
                            AsyncAPICall (SuccessListener, ErrorListener);
                        }
                    }
                }, ErrorListener);
            }
        }
    }, ErrorListener);
}
```

I want notification or callback or be informed by something that all Async calls are completed. Async calls are run in a different thread and due to for loop, many calls will be done simultaneously.

Is there any mechanism which informs me once all Async call received responses or I need to do manually something?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

@Khushbu Shah, I updated my answer, it changes a bit :) (it's pretty long).
To make sure it's working, I created a stand alone working example and use this API to test: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

```
private final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

    private final RestPostsService restPostsService = retrofit.create(RestPostsService.class);

    private Observable<Posts> getPostById(int id) {
        return restPostsService.getPostsById(id);
    }
```

***Solution1***: *Use when call multiple tasks in sequences, the result of previous tasks is always the input of the next task*

```
getPostById(1)
                .concatMap(posts1 -> {
                    //get post 1 success
                    return getPostById(posts1.getId() + 1);
                })
                .concatMap(posts2 -> {
                    //get post 2 success
                    return getPostById(posts2.getId() + 1);
                })
                .concatMap(posts3 -> {
                    //get post 3success
                    return getPostById(posts3.getId() + 1);
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(finalPosts -> {
                    //get post 4 success
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Final result: " + finalPosts.getId() + " - " + finalPosts.getTitle(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                });
```

***Solution2***: *Use when call multiple tasks in sequences, all results of previous tasks is the input of the final task (for example: after uploading avatar image and cover image, call api to create new user with these image URLs)*:

```
Observable
                .zip(getPostById(1), getPostById(2), getPostById(3), (posts1, posts2, posts3) -> {
                    //this method defines how to zip all separate results into one
                    return posts1.getId() + posts2.getId() + posts3.getId();
                })
                .flatMap(finalPostId -> {
                    //after get all first three posts, get the final posts,
                    // the final posts-id is sum of these posts-id
                    return getPostById(finalPostId);
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(finalPosts -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Final posts: " + finalPosts.getId() + " - " + finalPosts.getTitle(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });
```

***AndroidManifest***

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**root build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

    // Exclude the version that the android plugin depends on.
    configurations.classpath.exclude group: 'com.android.tools.external.lombok'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.com.rxretrofit"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
}
```

**model**

```
package app.com.rxretrofit;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
/**
 * -> Created by Think-Twice-Code-Once on 11/26/2017.
 */
public class Posts {
    @SerializedName("userId")
    private int userId;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("body")
    private String body;
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }
    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

**RestPostService.java**

```
package app.com.rxretrofit;

import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import rx.Observable;

/**
 * -> Created by Think-Twice-Code-Once on 11/26/2017.
 */

public interface RestPostsService {

    @GET("{id}")
    Observable<Posts> getPostsById(@Path("id") int id);
}
```

By the way, use **Rx + Retrofit + Dagger + MVP pattern** is a great combine.

Comment: I agree rxjava would be good here, but your example barely makes sense, expected zip() observeOn() and subscribeOn() at least

Comment: Thanks "@Think Twise Code Once". First I understand the RxJava and after that, I will try this solution.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I took a look at Observable.zip() before giving this answer, but I think this solution is more simple.

Comment: if you think this is a good solution you don't know how rxjava works

Comment: maybe you are right, I will try to go deeper in this case, I expect a better answer from you.

Comment: in that case I expect you to delete your answer

Comment: I think this answer is a great help for me. At least from this, I got the hint of RxJava and now I will learn that. @Tim, if you have an exact answer then you can give, but the hint is also fine when you are stuck and there is no answer.

Comment: @KhushbuShah You can take a look at my updated answer, tell me if you can't make it works as expected.

Comment: Ok.Sure. Thank you. I will try and let you know.