# Android AsyncTask RecyclerView does not populate

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I want to make an app lister application which fetches the application list via the packagemanager through an `AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<PackageSummary>>` nested in a singleton class. However, if and only if I implement the async task, the RecyclerView will not populate on the first OnCreate.

I am sure I am doing a silly mistake and/or do not understand AsyncTask and RecyclerView well enough, but for the love of me I cannot find the root of the issue.

[In my  toy app repository](https://bitbucket.org/itarill/toyapplister/branches/) I have prepared two, relatively cleaner branches for illustration purposes:

- One in which the packages are fetched in the main thread, and the recyclerview populates on first Oncreate (*git_UI_thread*).
- One in which an `AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<PackageSummary>>` class is called. The application persistence is not set yet (on purpose), and the `RecyclerView` will only populate after the application is rotated (*git_background_thread*).

For those who are not inclined to click on the bitbucket link above, the code snippet of the inside of my `AsyncTask` looks like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<SingletonPackageSummarySupplier.PackageSummary> packageSummaries) {
        super.onPostExecute(packageSummaries);
        isQueryingInProgress = false;
        packageSummaryList = packageSummaries;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<SingletonPackageSummarySupplier.PackageSummary> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        List<PackageSummary> installedPackages = new ArrayList<>();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList) {

            ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;

            installedPackages.add(new PackageSummary(resolveInfo.activityInfo));
        }

        return installedPackages;
    }
```

And this is my Main activity OnCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    psList = SingletonPackageSummarySupplier.getInstance(context).getPackageSummaryListReadOnly();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    recyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);


    adapter = new AdapterApplist(context, psList);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And this is how the singleton is fetched:

```
static SingletonPackageSummarySupplier instance;
public static SingletonPackageSummarySupplier getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new SingletonPackageSummarySupplier(context);
    } else{
        instance.updateInstance(context);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

P.S.: I think (but not sure) the singleton pattern is justified in order to diminish the changes of memory leaks.

P.S.2: I have read a couple questions about this, but none had an accepted / working solution.

Comment: where and when you are executing async task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either I was unable to implement the observer pattern (note that the asynctask was in a singleton class separate from the recyclerview and activity), or it is just not working well in this case.

Anyway, I ended up fixing the issue with the relatively new [lifecycle-aware components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html): MutableLiveData, LiveData and AndroidViewModel (instead of viewmodel, which does not get context as constructor parameter). It is simple and elegant.

The key part was this, in the activity:

```
    PackageSummarySupplier model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PackageSummarySupplier.class);
    model.getPackageSummaryList().observe(this, packageSummaryList -> {
        adapter = new AdapterApplist(context, packageSummaryList);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in your `postexecute` method of `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps: Update your data to AdapterApplist and notify it. Hence you should create a new method like:

```
public void setData(List<SingletonPackageSummarySupplier.PackageSummary> list)         
{ //reset your data ere
}
```

inside AdapterApplist class. Then, update your post:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<SingletonPackageSummarySupplier.PackageSummary> packageSummaries) {
        super.onPostExecute(packageSummaries);
        isQueryingInProgress = false;
        packageSummaryList = packageSummaries;
        adapter.setData(packageSummaryList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: This will cause that I need to pass on a RecyclerView.Adapter object to the Singleton. Also, the application list is an argument in the  RecyclerView.Adapter's constructor. Either way, even if I can get it to work it does not really help clean code. 

Or am I not understanding it well?

Comment: It is a dirty way to make it work. A clean code is to use Observer design pattern in this case

Comment: My google skills seem inadequate to find a good guide for this pattern (apart from data binding and butterknife) . Can you maybe provide me a link for one?

Comment: You can find an example here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983101/using-observable-in-android

My advice is to implement a simple one using pure Java (not Android) to understand it first